# Node.js can't compile one of the installed tests

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js

I am trying to port a PHP project to node.js

I installed node 0.10.26 using the universal installer for mac os x downloaded from node.org.  The path env contains the right dir paths to the executables..etc.

I converted the first file/module, tried to check its syntax using

```
node - p ~/path/with/no/spaces/to/myFile.js
```

The result is an error that reads:

```
Minis-Mac:Projects newbnz$ node -p ~/Projects/convert/application/models/mdAPI.js 
[eval]:1
/Users/maat/Projects/convert/application/models/mdAPI.js 
^
SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'newbnz'
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
    at startup (node.js:80:7)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I went ahead and tried to do the same with one of the test files that get installed with node as such:

```
Minis-Mac:Projects newbnz$ node -p  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/test/common.js

[eval]:1
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/test/common.js
^
SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'local'
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
    at startup (node.js:80:7)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I am running it on OS Mavericks.

Disclosure: i am c/c++ dev and a newbie to JS and node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am doing a port from PHP to Node, I missed an 'array' declaration at an obscure line at the 
beginning of the file.  i.e. a syntactic error.

After fixing the syntax error, I pushed my luck to see if i can use node -p as a means to check syntax only (posted somewhere in one of the questions on stack overflow), but it still didn't work.

The way I found the error is that I opened a new js file, started copying stmt by stmt till I found it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `-p` flag, which according to `node --help` causes the following:

```
  -p, --print          evaluate script and print result
```

And then you pass your application's file path, `~/path/with/no/spaces/to/myFile.js`, which is translated by your shell into `/Users/maat/Projects/convert/application/models/mdAPI.js`.

Now since you used the `-p` flag, that "path" you thought you were telling node to use to launch your application is actually interpreted as raw javascript as though it was passwed to the `eval` function.

And given the format of the path (starting with a `/` and with no enclosing single or double quotes around it), node interprets it as a javascript regular expression and then tries to evaluate it (with incorrect regex syntax) - thus causing the mysterious error in your console.

Long story short, remove the flag and you should get the behaviour that you want.

Comment: I removed the -p and tried it on the installed tests to avoid my own mistakes.  It still didn't compile successfully.  Here's the echo:

Minis-Mac:Projects newbnz$ node  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/test/common.js 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/test/common.js:9
});
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3